# C# I'd like to fix it when compiling an undefined formula

Tags: c#

I want to create a method that defines a formula when it is executed.

When the program was first launched, I want to read the formula (XML) from a data structure and fixed it to a method.

```
double SomeThing_Calculate(double[] v)
{
    double result;
    result = ???;
    return result;
}
```

if i put in "A * B + C - (D * A)" xml or excel etc...
then `result = v[0] * v[1] + v[2] - (v[3]*v[0]);`

```
void GetDamage(DmgInfo dmgInfo)
{
    GetStat(StatType.HP) = ???;
}
```

if i put in "HP - (1-Armor) * _dmgInfo.damage "  [underbar meaning Parameter value]
then `GetStat(StatType.HP) = GetStat(StatType.HP) - (1-GetStat(Armor))*dmgInfo.damage;`

I'm not sure. The Eval keyword doesn't seem to yield the same performance as writing directly on the code.

I know how to generate the same code using C # IL.
When the program is run, it analyzes the formular, finds the method with `Reflection` and inserts the IL code.

But I think it's too complicated and ignorant. I think there are other keywords or methods that I don't know to solve this problem.

When it is first executed, I want to find a way to fix string-type formulas to the method.

Comment: I would assume this is a game and not a general purpose formula evaluator.

Comment: generating IL-code and modifying run-time method is way too hard for this simple task, as for me. I suppose there will be just a couple of simple arithmetic actions, so you can write some simple class and serializer for this.

Comment: You can do this: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/715891/Compiling-Csharp-Code-at-Runtime

Comment: Otherwise you're looking for your own parser.

Comment: I am failing to understand exactly what the end goal is here. You want to evaluate a XML/Excel string, and have it evaluate in C#, but don't want to actually convert the formula to C# using IL? As stated above, this is already smells like overkill, but I don't know the overall design, so I won't make that assumption.  In either case, how else do you want a compiled language to dynamically evaluate a string formula short of parsing with Regex or some other similar way? Using Reflection or parsing the string is about your only options.

Comment: @Enigmativity the OP already stated they know how to generate the IL code and convert it to C#, looking for something else.

Comment: @ForeverZer0 - Yes, I suggested compile C# from source. That's different.

Comment: isn't it slow Reflection? if it is C, then i can just Use pointer, cuase i already know every stat location. but in C# doesn't use it(except unsafe).

Comment: You should look into the [C# scripting API](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples). Obviously depending on the performance requirements you could use a cached delegate and only update if the script changes.

Comment: DataBinder.Eval (stringFormula) does a parsing every time `GetDamage ()` is called. I want this to parse only once when the program runs and not afterwards.

Comment: @mikez That's what i want! :D Thank you. The keyword API seems to be the closest answer I need.

Comment: Why do you have to parse every time? The whole idea of using emitted IL code is to get your formula created once and run it with parameters anytime. On the other hand you have to reevaluate the value only if the underlying parameters changed.

Comment: @Enigmativity I was unaware of a difference between converting a string into a C# method dynamically at run-time and "from source" dynamically at run-time. Sounded a lot like just a semantic difference.

Comment: @ForeverZer0 - Sorry, I thought you were talking about emitting IL rather than compiling source.